# Volume mount in docker for postgres data

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to insert data into postgres using docker.

I have a folder in my code named data which has `insert` commands and has one file named *init.sql*.
I want to insert the data from `init.sql` present in folder data to tables present in docker.

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
  postgres:  
    image: postgres:11.6-alpine 
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
    volumes:
      - ./tables:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  data: {}
```

I am trying this but I get the error:

> initdb: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty

I think I am not using the correct use case, I am new to docker compose.
But is there any way, my use case can get satisfied?

Comment: Mhm... taking a second look at this, well, what you want to achieve cannot be executed with `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. This behaviour (of running a sql script at start) will **only** happen if the container is booted for the very first time

Comment: And if you want to do this, then you'll have to override the [`entrypoint`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint) in the compose file to achieve that.

Comment: ok thanks 
probably would need to do:
in volumes:
/data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by an improper usage of the `volumes` syntax for your [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).
In order to mount a named volume you have to just use its name like this:

```yaml
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

If your syntax begins with a `.` then it will be a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) from your host.

```yaml
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

The above code is mounting the host folder `data` relative to where you your *docker-compose.yml* is located.

This *docker-compose.yml* should do what you expect.

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
  postgres:  
    image: postgres:11.6-alpine 
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
    volumes:
      - ./tables:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  data:
```

---

If for some reason your volume has been created already, with an empty or no database, your first step should be running:

```sh
docker-compose down --volumes
```

From the documentation:

```
-v, --volumes           Remove named volumes declared in the `volumes`
                        section of the Compose file and anonymous volumes
                        attached to containers.
```

<sup>*From: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/*</sup>

Comment: Thanks but it does not insert the data present in file init.sql in folder data in postgres.

Comment: it should work with bind mount too, not just named volume

Comment: in this case, where is data relative to on the host?

Comment: @mike01010 which case to you relate to?

Comment: sorry..when you shared volume 'data'. is there a way to control where that storeage will be relative to the  host?  i can't do something like '/shared_data_storage/data' for shared volume, but i can do that for volume mounts.

Comment: @mike01010 you won't find the file as is on your host, the best is usually to mount that named volume in the distribution of your choice, then inspect files from there, e.g.: `docker run -ti --rm -v -data:/files_to_inspect alpine` then inside the container `ls /files_to_inspect` or if you want them back on your host, use the [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) commands.